# Cannot find module '@google-cloud/storage'

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions

I am using the GCP console on my browser. I have created a function as following:

```
function listFiles(bucketName) {
  // [START storage_list_files]
  // Imports the Google Cloud client library
  const Storage = require('@google-cloud/storage');

  // Creates a client
  const storage = new Storage();


  storage
.bucket(bucketName)
.getFiles()
.then(results => {
  const files = results[0];

  console.log('Files:');
  files.forEach(file => {
    console.log(file.name);
  });
})
.catch(err => {
  console.error('ERROR:', err);
    });
  // [END storage_list_files]
}

exports.helloWorld = function helloWorld (req, res) {
  if (req.body.message === undefined) {
    // This is an error case, as "message" is required
    res.status(400).send('No message defined!');
  } 
  else {
    // Everything is ok
    console.log(req.body.lat);
    console.log(req.body.lon);
    listFiles("drive-test-demo");
    res.status(200).end();
  }
}
```

Literally all I am trying to do right now is list the files inside a bucket, if a certain HTTPS trigger comes through.

my package.json file is as follows:

```
{
  "name": "sample-http",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "dependencies": {
    "@google-cloud/storage": "1.5.1"
  }

}
```

and I am getting the error "Cannot find module '@google-cloud/storage'"

Most queries I have seen thus far have been resolved by using npm install, but I don't know how to do that considering that my index.js and package.json files are stored in a zip file inside a gcloud bucket. Any advice on how to solve this would be much apreciated.

Comment: you should install npm and run `npm install`

Answer (score 28):

Open console, change dir to you functions project and type:

```
npm install --save @google-cloud/storage
```

That's all!